# How to convert python-request JSON results to csv?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests, export-to-csv

I am trying to get my list of contacts from my WIX website using their API endpoint url and the requests module in python. I am totally stuck.
Here's my code so far:

```
import requests

auth_key = "my auth key"
r = requests.get("https://www.wixapis.com/crm/v1/contacts", headers={"Authorization": auth_key})
print(r.status_code)
dict = r.json()
contacts_list = dict["contacts"]

for i in contacts_list:
    for key in i:
        print(key, ':', i[key])
```

Here is what I get:

```
200
id : long id string 1
emails : [{'tag': 'UNTAGGED', 'email': 'sampleemail1@yahoo.com'}]
phones : []
addresses : [{'tag': 'UNTAGGED', 'countryCode': 'US'}]
metadata : {'createdAt': '2020-07-08T22:41:07.135Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-07-08T22:42:19.327Z'}
source : {'sourceType': 'SITE_MEMBERS'}
id : long id string 2
emails : [{'tag': 'UNTAGGED', 'email': 'sampleemail2@yahoo.com'}]
phones : []
addresses : []
metadata : {'createdAt': '2020-07-03T00:51:21.127Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-07-04T03:26:16.370Z'}
source : {'sourceType': 'SITE_MEMBERS'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Each line is a string. I need each row of the csv to be a new contact (There are two sample contacts). The columns should be the keys. I plan to use the csv module to `writerow(Fields)`, where fields is a list of string (keys) such as `Fields = [id, emails, phones, addresses, metadata, source]`

All I really need is the emails in a single column of a csv though. Is there a way to maybe just get the email for each contact?

Comment: `emails`, `addresses`, and `metadata` all contain _multiple_ items each. How will theif contents map to columns of the CSV?

Comment: Yeah that's kind of the problem. All I really need is the email from emails. How can I get that out for each contact?

Comment: Well, for the email address, one way to handle it is to just "reach" into the data structure and grab the first entry in the contact list (and ignore any others). See my answer.

Comment: I foundprint(contact.keys())  <br/>very useful in this case.

Comment: Matt: Yes, note also that you can often use `print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))` to get a visual idea of how the data you're dealing with is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSV file with one column is basically just a text file with one item per line, but you *can* use the `csv` module to do it if you really want, as shown below.

I commented-out the 'python-requests' stuff and used some sample input for testing.

```
test_data = {
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": "long id string 1",
            "emails": [
                {
                    "tag": "UNTAGGED",
                    "email": "sampleemail1@yahoo.com"
                }
            ],
            "phones": [],
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "tag": "UNTAGGED",
                    "countryCode": "US"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "createdAt": "2020-07-08T22:41:07.135Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-07-08T22:42:19.327Z"
            },
            "source": {
                "sourceType": "SITE_MEMBERS"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "long id string 2",
            "emails": [
                {
                    "tag": "UNTAGGED",
                    "email": "sampleemail2@yahoo.com"
                }
            ],
            "phones": [],
            "addresses": [],
            "metadata": {
                "createdAt": "2020-07-03T00:51:21.127Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-07-04T03:26:16.370Z"
            },
            "source": {
                "sourceType": "SITE_MEMBERS"
            }
        }
    ]
}


import csv
import json
import requests


auth_key = "my auth key"
output_filename = 'whatever.csv'

#r = requests.get("https://www.wixapis.com/crm/v1/contacts", headers={"Authorization": auth_key})
#print(r.status_code)
#json_obj = r.json()

json_obj = test_data  # FOR TESTING PURPOSES
contacts_list = json_obj["contacts"]

with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as outp:
    writer = csv.writer(outp)
    writer.writerow(['email'])  # Write csv header.

    for contact in contacts_list:
        email = contact['emails'][0]['email']  # Get the first one.
        writer.writerow([email])

print('email csv file written')
```

Contents of `whatever.csv` file afterwards:

```
email
sampleemail1@yahoo.com
sampleemail2@yahoo.com
```

Comment: I ended up combining both methods. I reached into the data to pull out the emails and appended them to an empty list, but I also wrote them to a csv to save for later use. :) Thanks everybody! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Update:
As pointed by @martineau, I just saw you can array in few values, you need to cater it. You may make them string with `[].join()` in the for loop

you can write it to csv like this using csv package.

```
import csv, json, sys

auth_key = "my auth key"
r = requests.get("https://www.wixapis.com/crm/v1/contacts", headers={"Authorization": auth_key})
print(r.status_code)
dict = r.json()
contacts_list = dict["contacts"]
output = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
#insert header(keys)
output.writerow(data[0].keys()) 

for i in contacts_list:
      output.writerow(i.values())
```

At the end you can print and verify `output`